# Texture Baking in Cycles, I'm getting no Colour

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake some materials to use in Unity.

However the baked image textures do not capture the colour of the materials.

[image]

[image]

Comment: your images aren't loading properly, also, what map are you trying to bake, combined?

Comment: It's best to avoid plugging color output (from Voronoi texture in the top) into shader input, it won't necessarily work. As to baking I don't see anything really wrong as you're baking indirect and direct passes so including shadows on the diffuse pass. To bake only color choose Color pass only.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I managed to find a solution through trial and error with the nodes until I saw the material render completely in rendered viewport shading. I took your advice about plugging color output into shader input as well, and I switched to baking diffuse. Thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewGoodsell If you solved your problem, please write a detailed answer of what you did and mark it as accepted, that way the question will not be seen in the system as unsanswered. Your effort will help other users that run into a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Plugging my procedural textures and image textures on to a diffuse shader node before mixing fixed the problem I was having.